# removing outliers based on two columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Year Month Equipment   Weight
2017 1     TennisBall  5
2017 1     Football    4
2017 1     TennisBall  6
2017 1     TennisBall  7
2017 1     TennisBall  300
2017 2     TennisBall  300
2018 2     TennisBall  250
2018 2     Football    5
2018 2     TennisBall  6
2018 2     TennisBall  275
...
```

In the above example, it is normal for us to ship 300 units of Tennis balls only in the month of Feb, thus making the order of 6 units an outlier, whereas in Jan, the normal amount is ~5, making any larger orders in that month an outlier. I would like to drop the outliers based on looking at the weight per month. Is there a simple way to do this? I know I can do something along the lines of:

```
df1[np.abs(df1.Weight-df1.Weight.mean()) <= (5*df1.Weight.std())]
```

to grab anything with weight within 5 deviations of the average, but that won't take into account the by month part, where I can see dramatic shifts in weight because of what month it is. Thanks!

Edit:
For example, the desired output would be something like this:

```
Year Month Equipment   Weight
2017 1     TennisBall  5
2017 1     Football    4
2017 1     TennisBall  6
2017 1     TennisBall  7

2017 2     TennisBall  300
2018 2     TennisBall  250
2018 2     Football    5

2018 2     TennisBall  275
...
```

Where in Jan the outlier of 300 was removed (as in Jan this is above the norm) and in Feb the outlier of 6 was removed (would be in the norm in Jan, but as it happened in Feb, it is not normal)

Comment: Can you include the example dataframe and desired output.

Comment: Included. The example dataframe is the first dataframe. I added a desired output at the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem for groupby. You can solve this by creating two new columns containing the grouped means and standard deviations, and then filtering on those columns:

```
# Calculate difference between Weight and mean of group
df['Weight diff'] = df['Weight'].sub(df.groupby(['Year','Month','Equipment'])['Weight'].transform('mean'))
# Calculate standard deviation of group
df['std'] = df.groupby(['Year','Month','Equipment'])['Weight'].transform('std')

# Consider columns satisfying condition
# Include or condition accounting for NaN's from single value groups
df = df.loc[(np.abs(df['Weight diff']) <= df['std']) | (df['std'].isnull())]

# Remove unnecessary columns
df = df.drop(['Weight diff', 'std'], axis=1)
```

```
>>> print(df)

0   Year Month   Equipment  Weight
1   2017     1  TennisBall       5
2   2017     1    Football       4
3   2017     1  TennisBall       6
4   2017     1  TennisBall       7
6   2017     2  TennisBall     300
7   2018     2  TennisBall     250
8   2018     2    Football       5
10  2018     2  TennisBall     275
```